# How is magnetic moment of a surface current defined?

Tags: magnetic-fields, vectors, magnetic-moment

For current loops the definition of magnetic moment is $\textbf{m}=I\int d\textbf{S}$.
But say I've a cube with a surface current, how can we define magnetic moment in this case?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for any steady current distribution is
$$
{\bf m}= \frac 12 \int {\bf r}\times {\bf J}\, d^3x.
$$
This quantity is independent of the origin chosen for ${\bf r}$ because
$$
\int {\bf J} \, d^3x={\bf 0} 
$$
for a steady current that obeys $\nabla \cdot {\bf J}=0$.

I leave it up to you to specialize this general case to   one of a current supported on a surface.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was studying from Griffiths and he just defined it for a current loop. What textbook is a step advanced from it, so that after finishing it I will study that?

Comment: Read J. D. Jackson "Classical Electrodynamics" This is still the definitive textbook.

Comment: Thank you ,I'll try to study it.